# React: Invalid JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

When I fetched from the following URLs and tried to display them (via react-json-view), I ran into the error that **`property must be a valid JSON object`**.

```js
Promise.all([
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/initstate"),
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/racedata_json/"),
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/racerlog_json/"),
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/racerdata_json/"),
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/teamdata_json/"),
  ])
  .then(([usr, rcdata, rclog, rcrdata, tdata]) => {
    const initialState = {
      user: usr,
      raceapi: {
        racedata: rcdata, racerlog: rclog, racerdata: rcrdata, teamdata: tdata,
      }
    };
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <NTTrackerContextProvider initState={initialState}>
          <NTTracker/>
        </NTTrackerContextProvider>
      )
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
  })
```

**Each of the URLs above is a valid JSON object.** For example, the first URL looks like (in the body content):

```json
{"user": {"id": 1, "authenticated": true}, "csrftoken": "DSY"}
```

Here's my context provider:

```js
const initialState = {
  user: {username: "", authenticated: false, email: "",},
  raceapi: {
    racedata: {'data': null}, racerlog: {}, racerdata: {}, teamdata: {},
  }
};

const nttrackerReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOGGED_IN': {
      let {user, raceapi, ...etc} = state;
      let {userdata} = action;
      return {
        ...etc, user: {...user, ...userdata,}, raceapi: {...raceapi},
      }
    }
    // more cases below
    default: return state;
  }
};

const NTTrackerContextProvider = props => {
  const initState = props.initState || initialState;
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(nttrackerReducer, initState);

  return (
    <NTTrackerContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {props.children}
    </NTTrackerContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default NTTrackerContextProvider;
```

However, the output of `state.raceapi` (with `const [state, dispatch] = useContext(NTTrackerContext)`) looks like

[image]

Can anyone please help? I want the JSON data from the URLs to go into the state but I couldn't make the data go in.

I tried printing `{state.raceapi.racedata}` but it becomes a `Response` object; it seems like I'll be grabbing the data inside the object, but I don't know how to.

*Is it necessary to include another `fetch` in the function where I'll be calling the API, or is there a simpler way?*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After using fetch you probably need to use `result.json()` to convert it into a JS object.

Comment: @evolutionxbox like `state.raceapi.racedata.json()` or something else?

Comment: I would do it before setting the state. Try putting  `then(results => results.map(x => x.json()))` after `Promise.all`?

Comment: like [this image](https://i.imgur.com/Jp0bqIC_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand) @evolutionxbox?

Comment: Yeah, did that help? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch has more info on this

Comment: But when I try to access `{state.user.authenticated}`, react says that `{state.user}` is undefined. What could possibly be the case? The JSON for the user state is the example included in the question.

Comment: After adding the code suggested, what is the value of `json`?

Comment: as a matter of fact, when I logged `json`, it outputs [this image](https://i.imgur.com/87RpI8M_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand)

Comment: I think my suggestion was slightly incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Evolutionxbox set me into the right direction, starting with converting each Response object to JSON format:

```js
Promise.all([
  fetch(("http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/" + url)),
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/racedata_json/"),
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/racerlog_json/"),
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/racerdata_json/"),
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/teamdata_json/"),
  ])
  .then((([usr, rcdata, rclog, rcrdata, tdata]) => Promise.all(
    [usr.json(), rcdata.json(), rclog.json(), rcrdata.json(), tdata.json()]
  )))
  .then(([usr, rcdata, rclog, rcrdata, tdata]) => {
    const initialState = {
      user: usr,
      site: {locale: enUS,},
      raceapi: {
        // ...
```

Thanks for anyone that tried to help.